# min max date range selection in date range picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I am using Date Range Picker

Codes are here:

```
<input type="text" name="sample" id="sample" class="date_css" value="Select a date" />
```

Query is here:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
              $('#sample').daterangepicker({
                arrows:true,
                dateFormat: 'd-M-yy',
                rangeSplitter: 'to',
                datepickerOptions: {
                     changeMonth: true,
                     changeYear: true,
                     minDate: new Date("01/01/2011") //Account created date
                },

              });
         });
    </script>
```

**Question:** `datepickerOptions` Options are similar to same option using in datepicker in jquery ui. How can i use min max date selection while user selects date in particular range. (*ie* How to use `onSelect` Option within `datepickerOptions` and to restrict a range of selection)

Help Me

Thank in Advance...

Answer (score -1):

See [datepicker min max](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#min-max) and [datepicker date-range](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range).
The part you want is i think:

```
onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
    instance.settings.dateFormat ||
    $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
    selectedDate, instance.settings );
    dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
}
```

Then you combine it with "minDate" and "maxDate" options.

Comment: did u used date range picker, from where u would get the id. Ur script works for datepicker in jqueryui. Here in my case there would be a single text box. in which once user select date range. The range of date get updated

Comment: I understood by a range of date that you had two inputs.

You can use the "altField" option and set it to the second date with the "onSelect" function (jqueryui has examples for that).

Comment: Use date picker with date range picker library and show how it functions. i know to use with date picker but i dont know how to use with date range picker library

Comment: @mohan I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I an not asking about datepicker. i am asking how to restrict min and max date in date range picker library